# C# compiler bug? Object initializer syntax used for write-only property in Expression makes csc crash

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, expression-trees, compiler-bug, writeonly

You may consider this a bug report, however I'm curious if I am terribly wrong here, or if there is an explanation from Eric or someone else at Microsoft.

### Update

**This is now [posted as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678752/object-initializer-syntax-used-for-write-only-property-in-expression-makes-c-compiler-crash#) on Microsoft Connect.**

### Description

Consider the following class:

```
class A 
{
    public object B {
        set { }
    }
}
```

Here, `A.B` is a **write-only** but otherwise fine property.
Now, imagine we **assign it inside of expression**:

```
Expression<Func<A>> expr = 
    () => new A {
        B = new object { }
    };
```

This code makes C# compiler (both **3.5**.30729.4926 and **4.0**.30319.1) spit out

> **Internal Compiler Error (0xc0000005 at address 013E213F): likely culprit is 'BIND'.**

and crash.

However, **merely replacing object initializer syntax (`{ }`) with a constructor (`( )`) compiles just fine**.

### Full code for reproduction:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Test {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<A>> expr = 
            () => new A {
                B = new object { }
            };
    }
}

class A {
    public object B { set { } }
}
```

(And yes, I *did* hit it working on a real project.)

Comment: Looks like a bug, indeed. Of course you could argue it *can't* be a bug since the rules for expression tree construction are not defined anywhere in the spec, so any behaviour is technically legal (including choosing to format your HDD), but I think "bug" is more succinct :)

Comment: I wonder if someone can check if this compiles on Mono.

Comment: (concentrates hard, attempting to summon Eric by sheer willpower alone)

Comment: @gaearon I can check that later (not at PC at the moment); I'm also using the preview compiler (`async`) so can check that too.

Comment: *crackle* -- paging Eric Lippert to post 6471527, Eric Lippert to post 6471527 please -- *click*

Comment: Maybe the magic `@` sign will work. @Eric Lippert, you're needed here :)

Comment: *“Lipperto!”*, yelled Harry with a desperate expression.

Comment: Does it behave differently if you also provide a private getter?

Comment: @Frédéric nope, not how @replies work, can't notify anyone not involved with the thread already - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020

Comment: @Fred no, because he hasn't replied ... damnit @Daniel don't get ahead of me! :p (+1)

Comment: @Daniel, @jcolebrand, thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I can understand the limitation (too much noise maybe?), but that's too bad, it would make a nice feature :)

Comment: @Frédéric : No, it wouldn't.  There are many people with duplicate usernames.

Comment: Unless I'm mistake, Internal Compiler Errors are _always_ bugs, no matter what crazy illegal (or, in this case, not) syntax you throw at it.

Comment: I just checked and this compiles after adding a private getter returning null in Windows .NET 3.5 SP1.  It compiles without the getter under Mono 2.6.7.

Comment: I tested this as well and When VS2010 Crashed i debugged it and it returned the error: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not Eric Lippert (Oh, but could I be so dashing...), but as a former Visual Studio languages guy who can still search the sources, I *can* say two things about this:

1. Any time you see something that starts with "Internal Compiler Error" you have most definitely found a bug. That's what that error exists for, whether it's the C#, VB or C++ compiler. It's the "Oh, s**t, something just went really unexpectedly wrong!" throw-up-our-hands-and-bail-out error.
2. Beyond that, this is definitely a bug in the C# compiler that should be reported. The code that's crashing is assuming that when you're doing an initializer on a property that there's a getter it can look at and, hey, guess what? In this case, there isn't. Oddly enough, if I change the type being constructed to some type "C" instead of "object", I don't get the crash, so I'm guessing it's a failure further up the stack (i.e. the code never should have gotten down to the point where it was looking for the property getter).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the insight. In fact, first time I did the crash, it was with a custom type, not the `object` (but still using initializer syntax). If you don't get a crash, I'll update the question with another non-`object` sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found online related to the error,

Posted by Microsoft on 3/9/2010 at 10:58 AM

> Thanks everyone for the reports. I
>   believe that this issue has been fixed
>   post-RC. The problem is that the C#
>   compiler is crashing as it is tries to
>   report an error or warning. In several
>   cases we have seen the warning being
>   reported is that the LIB environment
>   variable contains an invalid path. To
>   avoid the crash, check that your LIB
>   environment variable contains valid
>   paths.
>
> Regards,
>
> Ed Maurer Development Manager, VB and
>   C# compilers

Comment: Source? So we can see the context of how (if) this is related?

Comment: Source: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534059/error-cs0583-internal-compiler-error-0xc0000005-at-address-3eac16a1-likely-culprit-is-begin

Comment: I think the error message is generic, and therefore is seen for different kind of crashes. However the issue I described seems to occur for everyone, not just me, so I doubt it has to do with LIB variable.